# Adding search bar and location button to MapKit view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, mapkit

This may be an easy solution but I've tried everything it seems. I cannot seem to add a search box and button to my MapKit view controller after my login window. I added my MapKit programatically rather than from the story board and can't seem to add any overlays onto it. Here is the code where I've previously tried to add `UIButton` and `UITextField` but it doesn't seem to appear so I've removed it.

I'm trying to get the user to input an address to where they'll get walking directions from their current location with a route poly overlay and also a button for finding their current location, like in the bottom corner of the normal Maps app.

```
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class mapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let mapView = MKMapView()
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupMapView()
        checkLocationServices()
    }
    
    func setupMapView() {
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 4000, longitudinalMeters: 4000)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
   
    func checkLocationAuthorization() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            followUserLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .denied:
            // Show alert
            break
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            // Show alert
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            break
        }
    }
    
    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            checkLocationAuthorization()
        } else {
            // the user didn't turn it on
        }
    }
    
    func followUserLocation() {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: 4000, longitudinalMeters: 4000)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    }
    
    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have managed to add a UISearchController:

```
let searchController: UISearchController = {
let sc = UISearchController()
sc.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
sc.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Search Directions", comment: "")
sc.searchBar.barTintColor = .systemPink
return sc
         
}()
```

Comment: Show the code where you tried to add the search bar.  Also, you can just set the `userTrackingMode` on the map view to have it track the user for you.  You can also add an [`MKUserTrackingButton`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkusertrackingbutton)

Comment: I've since removed it since it wasn't working and didn't save it to show sorry! I think the problem may be that after the transition from the first ViewController, the map seems to load into some kind of overlay or tray and maybe the UI element isn't being shown